# How "google news" can recognise that article in my website has few pages?

Tags: seo, google-news

How "google news" can recognise that article in my website has few pages?

**Description**:

My website has articles that I want will be taken by google news.
if article content too long in my website - he divided to pages (the problem should be for google how recognise that it same article).

**example from other website - same as in my website**:

http://money.howstuffworks.com/ponzi-scheme.htm   (1 page)

http://money.howstuffworks.com/ponzi-scheme1.htm  (2 page)

http://money.howstuffworks.com/ponzi-scheme2.htm  (3 page)

The solution that I know now : put every article in same page and not split to pages, but this solution reduce pages for index in my website and will reduce website rating in search results (please write if I am wrong).

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 1):

If you name your pages properly (as you do in your example) so that it display a relationship between the pages and/or link properly between these pages (i.e. use text such as "next page", "previous page", "page 2" etc) then you should be fine.

If you want to help them out even more use [`<link rel="next">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.2) and [`<link rel="prev">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.2). This details the relationship between pages in a series of pages.

Comment: thanks! i read blog that says  to put  article in 1 page only and split for the pages with javascript  :http://dailyseotip.com/possible-help-with-pagination-issue-relnext/485/ what do you think about that?

Comment: where google write that their crawl recognize "next page", "previous page", "page 2" etc?

Comment: where google write that their crawl recognise rel="next"? please can you give example of big websites that use this attribute?(stackoveflow.com not used when it more then 1 page of comments)

Comment: why a lot of big website puts their article(very long) in single page and not split on pages if no problem for google to recognise that is 1 article?